# Getting bits from Javascript Uint8ClampedArray

Tags: javascript, bit

I have a node server running, and in the server I generate and store into Redis a bunch of bits representing colours on a canvas. Every four bits of the stored bits represents a 4 bit colour. (Ex. If I store 001001101011111, then the colours I'm interested in are 0010, 0110, 1011, and 1111).

```
var byteArr = new ArrayBuffer(360000);
redis_client.set("board", byteArr);
redis_client.setbit("board", 360000, 0);

// There is some garbage at the beginning of the stored value, so zeroing them out.
for(var i = 0; i < 160; i++){
    redis_client.setbit("board", i, 0);
}
```

When a client connects to a server, I grab this string from Redis, and send it through a Websocket:

```
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    redis_client.get("board", function (error, result) {
        var initial_send = {"initial_send":true, "board":result};
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(initial_send));
    });
```

On the client side, I read the board like so:

```
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    var o = JSON.parse(event.data);
    board = o["board"];                                        
    var clampedBoard = new Uint8ClampedArray(board.length); 

    for(var i = 0; i < board.length; i++){                     
        clampedBoard = board[i];                               
    }
}
```

At this point, the length of the `board` is 45000, I believe this is because in Javascript, the smallest `TypedArray` constructor only allows 1 byte units. So because my initial ArrayBuffer was 360000 in size, when I receive it in the client, it is of size 360000/8.

This is where I'm having issues. At this point if I get `clampedBoard[0]`, it should give me the first 8 bits (the first two colours I care about), and I can do `clampedBoard[0]>>4`, and `clampedBoard[0]&15` to get me those two colours, and I can then
look them up in a map where the keys are 0000, 0001, etc,.

But that isn't what is happening.

Here's what I've tried, and what I know:

1. Printing values out on client-side: `console.log(clampedBoard[0])` gives back a [] looking null/undefined character on Chrome's console.
2. On the server side, when initializing `byteArr` and clearing the first 160 values to 0, I manually set the first 8 bits to '00111111', which is the binary representation of the ASCII character '?'.

When console.logging `clampBoard[0]` on the client side, I get the same [] null/undefined character, but when console.logging `board[0]`, it prints out a '?'. I'm not sure of why this is so.

And when attempting to look up in my map of colours by doing `clampedBoard[0]>>4`, it always defaults to the key in the dictionary which represents 0, even though it should be 0011.

If there is any more information I can provide, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can do:

```
board = o["board"];                                        
var clampedBoard = new Uint8ClampedArray(board);
```

So you won't need the value initialization loop.

Also, the way you were passing it to the object, the "stringification" will convert it to an string instead of array. In order to get an array, you'll need to create a Node.js' Buffer out of the ArrayBuffer, then convert it into a native array, as so:

```
var view = Buffer.from(result); 
var initial_send = {"initial_send":true, "board":[...view]};
```

Comment: Doing `console.log(clampedBoard[0].charCodeAt())` unfortunately gives me `0`.

Comment: If you do `console.log(board)`, what does it return?

Comment: Hm.... `board` is actually returning a string. You'll have to use a typed view before stringifying the initial send. `board: new UInt8ClampedArray(result)` back on websocket part of code.

Comment: I did what you said on the server side, and on the client side, I simply just did `console.log(board);`, and it just prints out `{}` on the console, and `console.log(board[0]);` also just prints out `0`.

Comment: Try that: `var view = Buffer.from(result); var initial_send = {"initial_send":true, "board":[...view]};`

Comment: That's what did it!

Comment: Nice, updating my main answer, then.

Comment: I think there is another issue with this (to be honest I'm not sure if its this, or something else), but, lets say I set the first four bits in Redis to be any value from 1000 to 1111 (the most significant bit being set), for some reason, `view`s length property increases, and when looping from `view` and printing out view[i], the places where I set '1000' always print out as 14, 15, 11, 15, 11, 13.

Comment: EDIT OF THE ABOVE READ THIS INSTEAD:

I think there is another issue with this (to be honest I'm not sure if its this, or something else), but, lets say I set one of the four bit values in redis to any value from 1000 to 1111 (any value that has the msb set), then whenever I retrieve it from redis, and print out the values from `view`, instead of getting the actual number, I get exactly 14, 15, 11, 15, 11, 13 instead of the actual four bit value. Not sure whats happening here.